# control Chip Select manually prior to data read in linux?

Tags: linux, beagleboard, spi

Hi I have a SPI touch device with 24 keys, each read will return 3 bytes, containing exact all 24 keys status. My hardware is a custom made beaglebone like device, spi0 is able to read its own write by connecting MISO to MOSI.

Everything (wiring, software) is working perfectly matching this guide: http://communistcode.co.uk/blog/blogPost.php?blogPostID=1

Now my touch device is CS active high device, but it requires to drive the chip select to low and back to high before actual read. I don't seems to have control with SPI cs value, I can only either control it within an actual read phase by specifying CS high or low. From my knowledge I have to use another GPIO to emulate the CS.

Question: any way to control cs freely? (i.e. set 0 or 1 by my code directly?)

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by pinmux the CS pin to a GPIO, and control it manually prior to actual communication.